# NodeJS Cucumber test are executed with not wait

Tags: javascript, node.js, cucumber, cucumberjs

My test fails. The test is executed immediately, and the automation test doesn't wait to finish some of the actions.

I saw an issue with cucumber and nodejs, but I am unsure how to handle it.

Here is my step js class:

```
const { Given, When, Then } = require('@cucumber/cucumber');

Given("I visit the automation-practice-form page", async () => {
    await page.goto("https://demoqa.com/automation-practice-form/");
});

When("I fill the form with correct data", async () => {
    await page.fill('#firstName', 'Tester');
    await page.fill('#lastName', 'Testerov');
    await page.fill('#userEmail', 'testingemail@testemail.com');
    await page.check('//*[@id="gender-radio-1"]/following-sibling::label');
    await page.fill('#userNumber', '1232131231');
    await page.click("#dateOfBirthInput");
    await page.click('(//div[@role="option"])[1]');
    await page.fill('#subjectsInput', 'Computer Science');
    await page.keyboard.press("Enter");
    await page.click('//*[@id="hobbies-checkbox-1"]/following-sibling::label');
    await page.setInputFiles("#uploadPicture", "uploads/test-image.jpg");
    await page.fill('#currentAddress', 'Test Address');
    await page.click("#state");
    await page.click('//*[@id="react-select-3-option-1"]', { force: true });
    await page.click("#city");
    await page.click('//*[@id="react-select-4-option-0"]');
});

When("click over the Submit button", async () => {
    await page.click("#submit");
});

Then("I will verify that the data ware filled in correctly", async () =>  {
    let name_actualResultElement = page.locator(
        '//*[contains(text(),"Student Name")]/following-sibling::td'
    );
});
```

and feature class:

```
Feature: Fill the form

    As a user
    I want to be able to fill the form

    Scenario: Fill the form with valid data
        Given I visit the automation-practice-form page
        When I fill the form with correct data
        When click over the Submit button
        Then I will verify that the data ware filled in correctly
```

Comment: Where is `page` defined?

Comment: Just use this boilerplate as a starter and you should be fine https://github.com/tallyb/cucumber-playwright